# jonesforth segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, gnu-assembler, forth

System I'm on:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

This is a 32-bit system.

Clone from the annexia repository:

```
git clone git://git.annexia.org/git/jonesforth.git
```

The build goes OK:

```
cd jonesforth

/tmp/jonesforth $ make
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static -Wl,-Ttext,0  -o jonesforth jonesforth.S
```

The tests however do not pass:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ make test
test_stack_trace.f ... --- .test_stack_trace.test   2016-09-17 17:44:59.488492834 -0500
+++ test_stack_trace.f.out  2016-09-17 17:33:11.171189490 -0500
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+TEST4+0 TEST3+0 TEST2+0 TEST+0 
+3 
+TEST4+0 TEST3+32 TEST2+0 TEST+0 
+TEST4+0 TEST3+0 TEST2+4 TEST+0 
+3 
+TEST4+0 TEST3+32 TEST2+4 TEST+0 
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'test_stack_trace.test' failed
make: *** [test_stack_trace.test] Error 1
```

Starting up jonesforth leads to a segmentation fault:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ cat jonesforth.f - | ./jonesforth 
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 11):

Removing `-Wl,-Ttext,0` from the Makefile entry for `jonesforth`:

```
jonesforth: jonesforth.S
    gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static $(BUILD_ID_NONE) -o $@ $<
```

seems to help. The build succeeds:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ touch jonesforth.S 
/tmp/jonesforth $ make
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static  -o jonesforth jonesforth.S
```

The tests pass:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ make test
test_stack_trace.f ... ok
test_stack.f ... ok
test_comparison.f ... ok
test_assembler.f ... ok
test_exception.f ... ok
test_read_file.f ... ok
test_number.f ... ok
```

And it starts up:

```
/tmp/jonesforth $ cat jonesforth.f - | ./jonesforth 
JONESFORTH VERSION 47 
14499 CELLS REMAINING
OK
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this. Was banging my head against the desk for several hours.